# How to migrate from ios UDID to identifierForVendor?

Tags: ios6, uniqueidentifier, udid

We are trying to think of a way to migrate our users from using UDID to identifierForVendor.

To migrate, we are thinking to submit an update before May 1st that uses both UDID and identifierForVendor so that we can identify the user and migrate him to the new system.

And here comes the problem :
Let's suppose that two months later we need to update our app again. We will no longer be able to access the UDID, so we will not be able to keep the code that migrates the users.

If a user fails to install the first update of our app and migrate himself, then if he downloads the 2nd update of our app directly, we will not be able to migrate him.

Is there a solution to this problem ?